# Custom pipelines in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I'm using ESB + BizTalk. In my itinerary, I make a call to an external website. In my

[image: SendPipeline]

I am calling ESB Itinerary Cache, the ESB Dispatcher. My issue is that the data being sent needs to be in JSON format for the request and the response.

[image: ReceivePipelin2]

Can I do this using the included pipeline components, or do I need to write custom pipeline code?

Comment: I assume JSONEncoder would come before the ESBItineraryCache on the Send pipeline, and after the ESBItineraryCache on the Return pipeline?

Comment: Possibly. Try that and see if it works.  If not try it the other way around,

Comment: Rolled back as you posted this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the JSON Encoder to the Encoder part of the Send Pipeline and JSON Decoder to Decode Sescion of the Receive Pipe.

You probably want the JSON Encoder after the ESB components in the send, and the JSON Decoder before the ESB component in the receive.

Comment: Did that. On the Receive side tried both before and after the ESB Components and still the same error.

Comment: Yes, and you posted a new question about that error.  See my comments against that